# grouped tableViewCell - no rounded corner after setting the background of a grouped table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

For the grouped `UITableViewCell`, I realized that if you set a background, there will be rounded corner at the top and bottom cell. But when you click it, it will show you the rounded corner at the selected state.

Comment: i just used some simple code like [tableItems setbackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[tblView.layer setCornerRadius:0.0f];
```

Comment: this gives tableView corner radius. Not cell though. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Why did you accept this answer if it's not the correct answer to your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Then go for Creating Sections,it will create what you want,each and every cell with round radius at top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

set the tableview's background color through code. For example:
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];